# Generation of an beam with an arbitrary initial profile

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, geometric-optics, diffraction

Is it possible to generate a beam with an arbitrary initial profile? For example, the finite Airy beam has an initial profile $$\phi(s,0)=exp(\alpha s)Ai(s).$$
In practice, this finite Airy beam is usually generated by Fourier transforming a Gaussian beam modulated with a cubic phase, which is not a general approach. So I wonder is there a general approach for generating a beam with an arbitrary specified initial profile?

Comment: Why isn't it a general approach?

Comment: @JoséAndrade Do you mean that we can just Fourier transform any given initial profile, and generate the beam via some Fourier optics technique? Then my question becomes that, given an arbitrary initial profile **in the Fourier domain**, are we always able to generate the beam?

Comment: yes, there are many techniques where you can access the spatial or time fourier domains (in the latter, frequency) and apply an arbitrary filter function in both amplitude and phase.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Thank you!